# Cisco Nexus 7009 line card replacement

Tags: cisco-nexus

I have A nexus 7009 switch that is just running as a single unit with just routing and only admin vdc and one prod vdc and no vpc,fabric path etc used on it . My question is we need to replace the older 2 cards. can we replace the M2 and F2 line cards below with new F3 line cards as is into the same slot and will it just take that same line card config? Will that work or Does it need a particular process ? even a simple link to a cisco website explain this is all I need as I cannot find a clear answer on this ? I found something about allocating the new line card respource in the admin vdc

M/F2 cards

N7K-M224XP-23L

N7K-F248XP-25E

F3 Card

N7K-F348XP-25

---

Hi rnrnx thanks for the comments   and the help is much appreciated

So as it stands we have the code version upgraded to the code to support F3 card so that is  ok  . We have on an off line backups  also and we have two separate core 7ks so will only be touching one at a time   so no service interruption should occur and we have a change window approved.   Based upon what you were saying and what we have currently assigned to the vdc the steps would  be below . Also should we suspend the vdc at some point in the process ?

First step 
F2 swap out to F3 
1)  Logical shut down of all interfaces on line card 5 N7K-F248XP-25E  i.e. shutdown interfaces xx
2)  Power down line card 5   module N7K-F248XP-25E
3)  Remove line card 5 and cables
4)  Insert  F3 N7K-F348XP-25 line card into slots 
5)  Patch cables to F3 card 
6)  On the admin vdc change resource allocation to limit-resource module-type m2xl F3 
7)  Power up line card 5 
8)  Un shut interfaces and confirm are working and showing up in PROD-B vdc
9)  Copy config to startup

Second steps 
M2 swap out to F3 
1)  Logical shut down of all interfaces on lines cards 3 and 4 N7K-M224XP-23L  i.e. shutdown interfaces xx
2)  Power down line card 3 and 4   module N7K-M224XP-23L
3)  Remove line card 3 and 4  and cables
4)  Insert  F3 N7K-F348XP-25 line card into slots
5)  Patch cables to F3 cards 
6)  On the admin vdc change resource allocation to limit-resource module-type F3 
7)  Power up line card 3 and 4 
8)  Unshut interfaces and confirm are working

Current Modules and VDC allocation 
Mod  Ports  Module-Type                         Model              Status

---

1    0      Supervisor Module-2                 N7K-SUP2E          ha-standby
2    0      Supervisor Module-2                 N7K-SUP2E          active *
3    24     10 Gbps Ethernet Module             N7K-M224XP-23L     ok
4    24     10 Gbps Ethernet Module             N7K-M224XP-23L     ok
5    48     1/10 Gbps Ethernet Module           N7K-F248XP-25E     ok

vdc PROD-B id 2
  limit-resource module-type m2xl f2e
  cpu-share 5
  allocate interface Ethernet3/1-24
  allocate interface Ethernet4/1-24
  allocate interface Ethernet5/1-48 (

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite directly, and not without interrupting service for a bit.  VDC's on the 7K can generally support a hybrid mode of *two* linecard types.  In your case it's M2-F2e.  If you were to swap both the M2 and the F2e out and replaced them with F3's you'd then need to change the VDC type.  The configuration from the F2e should be directly applicable on that F3 blade.  The M2 obviously has fewer ports.

I'd save the configuration (both on- and off- box) before making any changes.  I'd also suggest making sure you've upgraded to a relatively recent code version before swapping blades around.  At that point you might consider first swapping the F2e blade for the F3 and then switching the VDC mode to M2-F3.  At that point you should be able to swap the M2 blade.

Alternately - if you have the open slots - you could just establish a second F3-only VDC, get the blades up, pre-configure and just move the connections en-masse.  If the box is part of a redundant pair this could be argued to be the least disruptive.

Comment: hi rnxr added some comments to my original post

Answer (score 0):

Hi rnrnx thanks for the comments   and the help is much appreciated

So as it stands we have the code version upgraded to the code to support F3 card so that is  ok  . We have on an off line backups  also and we have two separate core 7ks so will only be touching one at a time   so no service interruption should occur and we have a change window approved.   Based upon what you were saying and what we have currently assigned to the vdc the steps would  be below . Also should we suspend the vdc at some point in the process ?

First step 
F2 swap out to F3 
- Logical shut down of all interfaces on line card 5 N7K-F248XP-25E  i.e.   shutdown interfaces xx
- Power down line card 5   module N7K-F248XP-25E
- Remove line card 5 and cables
- Insert  F3 N7K-F348XP-25 line card into slots 
- Patch cables to F3 card 
- On the admin vdc change resource allocation to limit-resource module-type m2xl F3 
- Power up line card 5 
- Un shut interfaces and confirm are working and showing up in PROD-B vdc
- Copy config to startup

Second steps 
M2 swap out to F3 
- Logical shut down of all interfaces on lines cards 3 and 4 N7K-M224XP-23L  i.e. shutdown interfaces xx
- Power down line card 3 and 4   module N7K-M224XP-23L
- Remove line card 3 and 4  and cables
- Insert  F3 N7K-F348XP-25 line card into slots
- Patch cables to F3 cards 
- On the admin vdc change resource allocation to limit-resource module-type F3 
- Power up line card 3 and 4 - Unshut interfaces and confirm are working

Current Modules and VDC allocation 
Mod  Ports  Module-Type                         Model              Status

---

1    0      Supervisor Module-2                 N7K-SUP2E          ha-standby
2    0      Supervisor Module-2                 N7K-SUP2E          active *
3    24     10 Gbps Ethernet Module             N7K-M224XP-23L     ok
4    24     10 Gbps Ethernet Module             N7K-M224XP-23L     ok
5    48     1/10 Gbps Ethernet Module           N7K-F248XP-25E     ok

vdc PROD-B id 2
  limit-resource module-type m2xl f2e
  cpu-share 5
  allocate interface Ethernet3/1-24
  allocate interface Ethernet4/1-24
  allocate interface Ethernet5/1-48